# WSO2-IS 6.0.0 Invalid username! Username should be an E-Mail address when trying to use non-email username

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 6.0.0 I am using the following configuration in the `deployment.toml` file so that, I can log in to my SPs with *email + password*.

```
[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true
```

But also, I am using my phone number for authentication as well. In that case, I can use the *phone number + password* to log in as well. This feature was working in 5.10 and I have migrated it to 6.0. But after migration, I am getting,

```
Invalid username! Username should be an E-Mail address
```

when I try to log in using the *phone number + password* combination. What are the steps that I can take to resolve this so that I can use the *phone number + password* and *email + password* to log in to my SPs?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that although you have enabled email domain name for authentication, you have not disabled the validation using email in the `deployment.toml` file. You can add the following configuration to your `deployment.toml` file to solve the issue.

```
[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true
disable_email_domain_validation = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can try multi-attribute login where you can use both email or mobile number as username with password.
Link: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/guides/login/multi-attribute-login/#enable-multi-attribute-login

Note that, Multi-attribute login will not work for the users who have same value for the claim. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/learn/configuring-uniqueness-of-claims avoids this conflict.